Unsupported Graphics Card Configuration error
Is there a fix for the Unsupported Graphics Card Configuration error?

A graphics card and river with support OpenGL 4.3 or higher is
required. Plugging all monitors into your primary graphics card might
resolve this issue. Installing the latest driver for your graphics
card could also help.

This is the full error prompt. I'm not seeing any viable solutions. Many suggest downloading a OpenGL file but I've heard this doesn't fix the problem.
I'm running two 4090s on a PC with Windows 11 with a Ryzen 9. Not sure what's causing this issue. Have already updated all the latest drivers.

This is caused by incorrect OpenGL rendering device setting under Windows operating systems, if you have multiple graphics cards. Particularly if you use more than one monitor each connected to a port on different graphics card, and your Blender startup file has multiple windows each on different monitors.
To fix this:

Open the Nvidia control panel (generally comes up if you search for "Nvidia" in the start menu)
On the left tree structure choose Manage 3D settings
Chose the Program Settings tab
Under 1. Select A program to customize: pick Blender (Blender.exe) from the dropdown menu. If there isn't one, add it manually by browsing to the location on your system where you installed Blender on.
Under OpenGL rendering GPU, change from Auto-Select to any other option like Nvidia GeForce RTX XXXX
Press apply at the bottom and restart Blender.



YESSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You're the man! Thanks so much. This has been causing a problem for weeks. Now I can finally render on this machine!

Don't forget to upvote the post that helped you. If you feel it completely solved your issue consider marking it as accepted.
