Selecting correct graphics card
I've installed blender on a windows machine, but launching it produces the error:

This is despite the fact that I've set blender to use my 3060,

And nvidia's software (geforce experience) says my drivers are up to date.
Is my graphics card too old? Or is there something else going on?
I also tried with the old UI (though there is a warning that windows now manages the choice of graphics card, hence above).


Did you try plugging all monitors into your graphics card like the error says?

Generally speaking this forum is more for asking a question about how to use Blender itself. Hardware oriented posts are better for the Blender Discord or BlenderArtists forums.

My mistake. I saw some other hardware posts when looking for duplicates & (erroneously) generalized. It's a laptop, so no plugging involved.

Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/322593/unsupported-graphics-card-configuration-error/322594#322594

No it does not. You linked the same solution I explained I already tried in the original post. It just looks different because that question is using the older nvidia UI instead of managing with windows as is now advised (I did try it both ways for completeness, but no luck).
