Blender - Unsupported Graphics Card Configuration
I have installed the latest version of Blender (4.2.3 LTS) on my laptop - ASUS TUF GAMING A15 with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 Laptop GPU. I can't even open blender because this error pops up. What can I do? I don't know a lot about GPUs, I'm just trying to download Blender for my graphic design classes... I have already installed the latest driver NVIDIA Studio Driver - WHQL Driver Version: 565.90 and I still have this problem. I have also tried installing older versions of Blender but nothing works.


Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/322593/unsupported-graphics-card-configuration-error/322594#322594

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried it ealier and no:(

If you are on a laptop it most likely has two graphics cards, and by default it is probably trying to run Blender in the low performance integrated one, you have to tell it to run Blender using the Nvidia one

I did try changing OpenGl from auto to my graphics card but no luck. I had a BIOS update for my Dell 9510 that is causing other issues as well. My backlight button keys no longer work. Both these issues started at the same time and may be connect. Either way, I still am not able to open Blender 4.2 even though I was previously able to.

Hi, welcome to BSE! Please do not use the answer section to reply to comments on your question. Use the comments section instead. And for any additional information to your question, please [edit] your question to have those details in proper display. Comments are not referenced equally and can be removed.
